# AADB2C following Salesforce guide for custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I’m currently trying to follow the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom) to setup our AADB2C IDProvider as a RP to Salesforce using Saml2.

Although the initial few steps are ok…

1. The new salesforce button is displayed in the login page.
2. When pressed leads me to the salesforce login page
3. I can login into salesforce.

The issue occurs when I am redirected back to AADB2C: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenantname}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/as

**results in a 404 File or resource not found.**

Do you know if this is the correct url to redirect back to AADB2C?
I’ve tried to use App Insights analytics (trace) but cannot find any issue in there (I believe because the issue is not logged as the resource not found)

On the bigger picture, my base custom policy is setup for openid, but this salesforce policy is setup to follow a user journey that consumes saml2 … how does that work for it to be able to understand both protocols?

If I change setup on the RP policy from openid to saml2

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />

 <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
       <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
       <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
```

I can then access to saml metadata on that policy, but I lose capability of testing it up using Azure dashboard. Is there a way I can test it then?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please confirm the the ACS URL that you are registered with Salesforce? It should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer`. Is "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase" the name of your base file?

Comment: hi Chris, the url am using ACS URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/as as advised on the Microsoft [wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom) . Yes, "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase" that's my base policy.

Comment: In the meanwhile changed to the ACS URL you advised above and seems to be working in terms of going back to AAD B2C, but now it seems is not using right certificate to validate answer from SF: ``` {"Values":[{"Key":"Validation","Value":{"Values":[{"Key":"SubmittedBy","Value":"SalesforceExchange"},{"Key":"ProtocolProviderType","Value":"SamlProtocolProvider"},{"Key":"Exception","Value":{"Kind":"Handled","HResult":"80131500","Message":"The claims provider response has an invalid signature.","Data":{}}}]}}]} ```

Comment: what was missing was to setup the certificate in aadb2c and give the right user account permissions in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set up the certificate in aadb2c. Also, you need to ensure that the Reply URL and Redirect URIs are matching, and the App ID matches the Client ID.